# Computer froze and unable to restart for tens of minutes : can my syslog show if the trouble comes from a memory stick, a package or its power unit?

Tags: logs, cpu, syslog, freeze

I encounter a bug that made my computer, under *Debian 10*, crash two times in ten days, and being unable to restart for ten minutes to half an hour.

Today during an *Eclipse* session, before while playing a game.
During my *Elipse* session today, I'm opening a web page on *Firefox*, and the computer frozes but the mouse is still able to move :

The computer is then unable to restart (even no display output) from 10:09 to 10:56
Here what my `syslog` says :

```
Feb 14 09:44:35 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Feb 14 09:44:40 bouleau gnome-shell[1842]: value "-1,000000" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'width' of type 'gfloat'
Feb 14 09:44:40 bouleau gnome-shell[1842]: value "-1,000000" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'height' of type 'gfloat'
Feb 14 09:44:40 bouleau gnome-shell[1842]: value "-1,000000" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'width' of type 'gfloat'
Feb 14 09:44:40 bouleau gnome-shell[1842]: value "-1,000000" of type 'gfloat' is invalid or out of range for property 'height' of type 'gfloat'
Feb 14 09:44:41 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Feb 14 09:44:41 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Feb 14 09:44:41 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Feb 14 09:45:01 bouleau CRON[5284]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 14 09:46:48 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Feb 14 09:46:49 bouleau org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1842]: Window manager warning: Window 0x6800003 (Eclipse) sets an MWM hint indicating it isn't resizable, but sets min size 449 x 300 and max size 2147483647 x 2147483647; this doesn't make much sense.
Feb 14 09:47:00 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/marc/dev/Java/comptes-france/geographie/dev/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.16.0.20200318-1040.xml
Feb 14 09:47:00 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Feb 14 09:47:05 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Feb 14 09:47:05 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Feb 14 09:47:05 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Feb 14 09:47:14 bouleau PackageKit: daemon quit
Feb 14 09:47:14 bouleau systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Feb 14 09:47:14 bouleau systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Feb 14 09:49:06 bouleau _home_marc_eclipse_java-2020-03_eclipse_.desktop[1842]: Warning: NLS missing message: MavenImpl_error_lookup in: org.eclipse.m2e.editor.internal.messages
Feb 14 09:55:01 bouleau CRON[5564]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 14 09:58:21 bouleau rtkit-daemon[827]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 14 09:58:21 bouleau rtkit-daemon[827]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 14 10:05:01 bouleau CRON[5751]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540747] list_del corruption. next->prev should be ffff8e7ab9011680, but was fffb8e7ab9011680
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540759] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540760] kernel BUG at lib/list_debug.c:56!
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540766] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540768] CPU: 3 PID: 65 Comm: kswapd0 Tainted: P           OE     4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.171-2
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540769] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P9X79 PRO, BIOS 1104 04/10/2012
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540775] RIP: 0010:__list_del_entry_valid.cold.1+0x20/0x47
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540777] Code: ae 49 b0 e8 90 24 ff ff 0f 0b 48 89 fe 48 89 c2 48 c7 c7 20 af 49 b0 e8 7c 24 ff ff 0f 0b 48 c7 c7 d0 af 49 b0 e8 6e 24 ff ff <0f> 0b 48 89 f2 48 89 fe 48 c7 c7 90 af 49 b0 e8 5a 24 ff ff 0f 0b
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540778] RSP: 0018:ffffb2b6437d7bf0 EFLAGS: 00010246
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540779] RAX: 0000000000000054 RBX: ffff8e7f0d1ad140 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540780] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff8e7f23ad66b8 RDI: ffff8e7f23ad66b8
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540781] RBP: ffffb2b6437d7d80 R08: 00000000000004e3 R09: 0000000000000004
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540782] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffffb0bfa6ee R12: ffff8e7f1e479b40
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540783] R13: ffffffffaf86d890 R14: ffff8e7ab9011680 R15: ffff8e7ab90118c0
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540784] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8e7f23ac0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540785] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540786] CR2: 00007efd0d905000 CR3: 00000006c440a001 CR4: 00000000000606e0
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540787] Call Trace:
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540794]  __list_lru_walk_one+0xf9/0x170
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540798]  ? __lock_parent+0x70/0x70
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540800]  list_lru_walk_one+0x4a/0x70
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540802]  prune_dcache_sb+0x47/0x70
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540804]  super_cache_scan+0xf6/0x1a0
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540809]  do_shrink_slab+0x125/0x270
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540811]  shrink_slab+0x216/0x2b0
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540813]  shrink_node+0xe8/0x460
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540814]  kswapd+0x3cd/0x6c0
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540816]  ? mem_cgroup_shrink_node+0x170/0x170
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540819]  kthread+0x112/0x130
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540821]  ? kthread_bind+0x30/0x30
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540825]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540827] Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy snd_seq snd_seq_device fuse bnep xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo nft_counter xt_addrtype nft_compat nft_chain_nat_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c nf_tables nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc vboxnetadp(OE) aufs(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) overlay vboxdrv(OE) uas usb_storage usblp intel_rapl snd_hda_codec_hdmi squashfs zstd_decompress xxhash loop x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp joydev nvidia_drm(POE) ath3k kvm_intel bluetooth kvm drm_kms_helper snd_hda_codec_realtek irqbypass drm snd_hda_codec_generic crct10dif_pclmul jitterentropy_rng crc32_pclmul hid_generic drbg ghash_clmulni_intel usbhid snd_hda_intel ansi_cprng intel_cstate eeepc_wmi hid snd_hda_codec ecdh_generic
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540851]  asus_wmi intel_uncore nvidia_modeset(POE) snd_hda_core sparse_keymap rfkill snd_hwdep video pcc_cpufreq intel_rapl_perf wmi_bmof pcspkr snd_pcm sg snd_timer mei_me snd mei iTCO_wdt soundcore iTCO_vendor_support evdev nvidia(POE) ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb sr_mod cdrom sd_mod crc32c_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel ahci xhci_pci libahci aes_x86_64 xhci_hcd libata ehci_pci crypto_simd cryptd ehci_hcd glue_helper e1000e usbcore scsi_mod lpc_ich i2c_i801 mfd_core usb_common wmi button
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540873] ---[ end trace 7712cfcfc33c5c74 ]---
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540875] RIP: 0010:__list_del_entry_valid.cold.1+0x20/0x47
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540875] Code: ae 49 b0 e8 90 24 ff ff 0f 0b 48 89 fe 48 89 c2 48 c7 c7 20 af 49 b0 e8 7c 24 ff ff 0f 0b 48 c7 c7 d0 af 49 b0 e8 6e 24 ff ff <0f> 0b 48 89 f2 48 89 fe 48 c7 c7 90 af 49 b0 e8 5a 24 ff ff 0f 0b
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540876] RSP: 0018:ffffb2b6437d7bf0 EFLAGS: 00010246
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540877] RAX: 0000000000000054 RBX: ffff8e7f0d1ad140 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540878] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff8e7f23ad66b8 RDI: ffff8e7f23ad66b8
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540879] RBP: ffffb2b6437d7d80 R08: 00000000000004e3 R09: 0000000000000004
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540880] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffffb0bfa6ee R12: ffff8e7f1e479b40
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540881] R13: ffffffffaf86d890 R14: ffff8e7ab9011680 R15: ffff8e7ab90118c0
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540882] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8e7f23ac0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540883] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540884] CR2: 00007efd0d905000 CR3: 00000006c440a001 CR4: 00000000000606e0
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656466] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656472] rcu:    3-....: (5249 ticks this GP) idle=3b6/1/0x4000000000000002 softirq=2836759/2836759 fqs=2617 
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656473] rcu:     (t=5250 jiffies g=5381237 q=838)
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656475] NMI backtrace for cpu 3
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656477] CPU: 3 PID: 31839 Comm: Cache2 I/O Tainted: P      D    OE     4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.171-2
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656478] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P9X79 PRO, BIOS 1104 04/10/2012
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656479] Call Trace:
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656482]  <IRQ>
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656487]  dump_stack+0x66/0x81
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656489]  nmi_cpu_backtrace.cold.4+0x13/0x50
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656492]  ? lapic_can_unplug_cpu+0x80/0x80
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656495]  nmi_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0xf9/0x100
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656497]  rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0x9b/0xcb
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656498]  rcu_check_callbacks.cold.81+0x1db/0x335
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656501]  ? tick_sched_do_timer+0x60/0x60
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656503]  update_process_times+0x28/0x60
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656504]  tick_sched_handle+0x22/0x60
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656506]  tick_sched_timer+0x37/0x70
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656507]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0x100/0x280
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656509]  hrtimer_interrupt+0x100/0x220
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656511]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x6a/0x140
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656514]  apic_timer_interrupt+0xf/0x20
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656515]  </IRQ>
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656518] RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x54/0x190
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656519] Code: 81 e6 00 ff ff ff 75 5f f0 0f ba 2f 08 8b 07 72 56 89 c2 30 e6 a9 00 00 ff ff 75 47 85 d2 74 0e 8b 07 84 c0 74 08 f3 90 8b 07 <84> c0 75 f8 b8 01 00 00 00 66 89 07 c3 8b 37 81 fe 00 01 00 00 75
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656520] RSP: 0018:ffffb2b643a7fcd0 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656522] RAX: 0000000000180101 RBX: ffff8e7a36f71140 RCX: 0000000100000000
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656522] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff8e7f1e479b40
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656523] RBP: ffff8e7f14b7a500 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffb2b643a7fc80
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656524] R10: ffffe19718d8f340 R11: ffff8e7f15ccf490 R12: 0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656525] R13: ffff8e7f1e479b40 R14: ffff8e79b6f71140 R15: 0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656527]  _raw_spin_lock+0x1c/0x20
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656530]  list_lru_add+0x64/0x1a0
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656532]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656534]  ? dput.part.34+0x32/0x140
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656536]  d_lru_add+0x34/0x40
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656538]  dput.part.34+0x124/0x140
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656540]  terminate_walk+0x83/0x100
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656542]  path_lookupat.isra.48+0xa3/0x220
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656544]  ? futex_wake+0x90/0x170
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656545]  filename_lookup.part.62+0xa0/0x170
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656547]  ? __check_object_size+0x162/0x180
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656550]  ? strncpy_from_user+0x47/0x1a0
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656551]  ? getname_flags+0x6a/0x1e0
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656553]  do_faccessat+0xac/0x250
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656556]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656558]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656559] RIP: 0033:0x7f9a970b45c7
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656560] Code: 77 01 c3 48 8b 15 c9 08 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 66 90 b8 15 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 01 c3 48 8b 15 99 08 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 b8
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656561] RSP: 002b:00007f9a8a83bb68 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000015
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656563] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007f9a713fa2f0 RCX: 00007f9a970b45c7
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656563] RDX: 0000000080070057 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 00007f9a78874508
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656564] RBP: 00007f9a8a83bbe0 R08: 0000000000000008 R09: 0000000000000008
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656565] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000002
Feb 14 10:09:11 bouleau kernel: [147123.656566] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 00007f9a738ca330 R15: 0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436561] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#5 stuck for 22s! [StreamT~ns #935:5811]
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436564] Modules linked in: snd_seq_dummy snd_seq snd_seq_device fuse bnep xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo nft_counter xt_addrtype nft_compat nft_chain_nat_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c nf_tables nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc vboxnetadp(OE) aufs(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) overlay vboxdrv(OE) uas usb_storage usblp intel_rapl snd_hda_codec_hdmi squashfs zstd_decompress xxhash loop x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp joydev nvidia_drm(POE) ath3k kvm_intel bluetooth kvm drm_kms_helper snd_hda_codec_realtek irqbypass drm snd_hda_codec_generic crct10dif_pclmul jitterentropy_rng crc32_pclmul hid_generic drbg ghash_clmulni_intel usbhid snd_hda_intel ansi_cprng intel_cstate eeepc_wmi hid snd_hda_codec ecdh_generic
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436585]  asus_wmi intel_uncore nvidia_modeset(POE) snd_hda_core sparse_keymap rfkill snd_hwdep video pcc_cpufreq intel_rapl_perf wmi_bmof pcspkr snd_pcm sg snd_timer mei_me snd mei iTCO_wdt soundcore iTCO_vendor_support evdev nvidia(POE) ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb sr_mod cdrom sd_mod crc32c_intel mxm_wmi aesni_intel ahci xhci_pci libahci aes_x86_64 xhci_hcd libata ehci_pci crypto_simd cryptd ehci_hcd glue_helper e1000e usbcore scsi_mod lpc_ich i2c_i801 mfd_core usb_common wmi button
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436604] CPU: 5 PID: 5811 Comm: StreamT~ns #935 Tainted: P      D    OE     4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.171-2
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436605] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P9X79 PRO, BIOS 1104 04/10/2012
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436610] RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0xfc/0x190
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436612] Code: 00 8b 07 85 c0 75 0d be 01 00 00 00 f0 0f b1 37 85 c0 74 38 89 c8 c1 e8 10 66 87 47 02 89 c6 c1 e6 10 75 3f 31 f6 eb 02 f3 90 <8b> 07 66 85 c0 75 f7 41 89 c0 66 45 31 c0 44 39 c1 74 67 c6 07 01
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436613] RSP: 0018:ffffb2b649f57dc0 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436614] RAX: 0000000000180101 RBX: ffff8e7f1e479b40 RCX: 0000000000180000
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436615] RDX: ffff8e7f23b62d80 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff8e7f1e479b40
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436616] RBP: ffff8e7bf10fd800 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436617] R10: ffffb2b649f57dd8 R11: ffff8e7b710fd780 R12: 0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436618] R13: ffff8e7b710fd800 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8e7f16fa5000
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436619] FS:  00007f749bb34700(0000) GS:ffff8e7f23b40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436620] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436621] CR2: 00007f9a70a96010 CR3: 00000005ea4ba005 CR4: 00000000000606e0
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436622] Call Trace:
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436627]  _raw_spin_lock+0x1c/0x20
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436630]  list_lru_del+0x57/0x150
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436634]  d_lru_del+0x3d/0x50
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436636]  __dentry_kill+0x149/0x170
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436638]  dentry_kill+0x4d/0x190
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436639]  dput.part.34+0xf0/0x140
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436641]  do_renameat2+0x3cb/0x560
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436643]  __x64_sys_rename+0x1c/0x20
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436646]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436647]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436649] RIP: 0033:0x7f74c1ddf6d7
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436650] Code: e8 6e e9 07 00 85 c0 0f 95 c0 0f b6 c0 f7 d8 5b c3 66 90 b8 ff ff ff ff 5b c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 b8 52 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 01 c3 48 8b 15 89 d7 14 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 b8
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436651] RSP: 002b:00007f749bb338c8 EFLAGS: 00000286 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000052
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436652] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007f74c1ba89d0 RCX: 00007f74c1ddf6d7
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436653] RDX: ffffffffffffff40 RSI: 00007f748561a688 RDI: 00007f748561ae88
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436654] RBP: 00007f748561a688 R08: 00007f74c1ba89d0 R09: 00000000000ffff0
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436655] R10: 4403a5a2c8eaa330 R11: 0000000000000286 R12: 00007f74856d4c80
Feb 14 10:09:18 bouleau kernel: [147130.436656] R13: 0000000000002368 R14: 00007f749bb34700 R15: 00007f748561ae88
Feb 14 10:56:11 bouleau systemd-modules-load[389]: Inserted module 'lp'
Feb 14 10:56:11 bouleau systemd-modules-load[389]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Feb 14 10:56:11 bouleau kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.0-14-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30)
Feb 14 10:56:11 bouleau systemd-modules-load[389]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Feb 14 10:56:11 bouleau kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-14-amd64 root=UUID=0e3b15aa-0b00-4c0b-a0e5-3e2038185527 ro quiet
```

1. Is `Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540747] list_del corruption. next->prev should be ffff8e7ab9011680, but was fffb8e7ab9011680` a corruption :

- in a package
- or in a memory stick?

2. If it was in a memory stick, the computer might had restarted smoothly. But it didn't.
   Is my issue related to it's power supply at the same time?

What else could I search for?

Comment: You might want to ask in a kernel forum: *Feb 14 10:08:50 bouleau kernel: [147102.540760] kernel BUG at lib/list_debug.c:56!*

Comment: @EduardoTrápani The line involved in `list_debug.c` is just a kind of assert that detects that a chained list (I don't know the exact translation sorry) carries some wrong element. But without more information in the logs, I fear I won't find more explanation about the context that made this freezing happen.

Comment: It looks like the error occured whilst swapping, so perhaps your swap device is corrupting data. Try running without swap for a while, or move it to another device.

Comment: @meuh SSD drives can have corrupted data too? It's the ones I have. I believed that this kind of corruption could only occur on memory or magnetic hard drives. But thanks for the idea !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It went that my computer was broken : two memories sticks and one DIMM support on the motherboard were badly working and had to be removed or disabled.

The message :

next->prev should be fff **f** 8e7ab9011680
but was fff **b** 8e7ab9011680

hinted me to such failure. Because a pointer changing it's value by a single bit and this one being a very high value one, was very suspicious.